# ASE Sybase BLOB

Tags: sap-ase

hi I want to write a file into a column of a blob data type,can some one pls send me the syntax for it. Appreciate if you could also send me the syntax for retrieving the file while doing the select as well.Thanks.

Comment: We need more information. Is the content of the entire file going into a single blob? Is there one file only, or several files?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `readtext` and `writetext` functions :

[writetext](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1251e/commands/@ebt-link;nh=1;pt=1648;lang=el?target=%25N%15_53775_START_RESTART_N%25;;__next_hit__=18128;DwebQuery=writetext&DwebSearchAll=1) permits non-logged, interactive updating of an existing text or image column

[readtext](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1251e/sqlug/@Generic__BookView;lang=el?DwebQuery=readtext&DwebSearchAll=1) reads text and image values, starting from a specified offset and reading a specified number of bytes or characters